# Azure CDN Edge server issue

Tags: azure-cdn

I am trying to download the file using CDN edge server, but it gives 403 - forbidden error.

I have created the end point long back, so I dont remember either I created the token auth for this or not.

Does anyone have any idea after creating the token auth where the info goes so that I can see what is the expiry date and key value for the same.

Please let me know if any more information is required on this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a token, you will need to go to the 'manage' tab at the top bar of the CDN profile blade in portal.azure.com. 
See this for screenshots and steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth